# Android - App crashed when stopping MediaPlayer onPause

Tags: android

Getting strange errors when attempting to stop the MediaPlayer from playing when the activity goes into onPause or onStop.. Any suggestions? Thanks for any and all help!

Here is the code for my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lyricistintro);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();

    Button yesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.stop();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LyricList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

  public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    mp.stop();
 }

  public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mp.pause();
 }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The instance variable MediaPlayer mp; is never initialized. mp is null.

In onCreate you have re-declared and initialized

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lyricistintro);
```

mp here is local to onCreate.

Should be

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lyricistintro);

//and please replace your code in onstop with this 

 if (mp.isPlaying()) { 
      mp.stop(); 
 }

//and Onpause code should be replced with 

if (mp.isPlaying()) { 
  mp.pause(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The instance variable `MediaPlayer mp;` is never initialized. `mp` is null.

In `onCreate` you have re-declared and initialized

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lyricistintro);
// mp here is local to onCreate.
```

Should be

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lyricistintro);
```

Comment: Dang, I can't believe I was missing that...boy staying up as late as possible really does not help my programming thought process...Thank you so much!